# javascript if statement returns an error when json value is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the javascript below, it works only when there is no null value in the json data output, however when there is a null json output as in

```
{"id":30,"name":"John Don","email":"abcd@gmail.com","latest_payment":null}
```

i get an error.

***Uncaught TypeError: value.latest_payment is null***

```
JQuery.ajax({
                 type:"GET",
                 url : '/list',
                 data:{tenantSelected:tenantSelected},
                dataType : "json",
                 success:function(data)
                 {
                    jQuery.each(data, function(key,value){
                        if(tenantSelected == value.id){

                        var x=value.latest_payment;
                        if(x !== null) { //conditional statement to check if null
                        console.log(value.latest_payment);
                        } else {
                          console.log("No Data");
                          }        
                        
                    }
                    });                     
                 }
              });
```

Here is sample json output.

```
[{{"id":29,"name":"Jane Doe","email":"xyz@gmail.com","latest_payment":{"id":44,"amount":120000,"rent_from":"2020-01-01","rent_to":"2020-03-01","tenant_id":29},},//This returns correct output

{"id":30,"name":"John Don","email":"abcd@gmail.com","latest_payment":null}] //returns an error Uncaught TypeError: value.latest_payment is null
```

And ideas?

Comment: So... check if `value` is null?

Comment: You're already doing `if(x !== null)` before logging the value. Do the same later before using the value.

Answer (score -1):

Inside the if statement try this

```
if(value && value.latest_payment)
```

Answer (score -1):

try like this

```
if(value && value.latest_payment) { 
console.log(value.latest_payment);
} else {
console.log("No Data");
}
```